# How can I create a login form in preference fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

This is my first day for Android....

I studied preference activity and fragment, and I wondering how to create the login form in a preferenceFragment class and PreferenceScreen xml.

1. Let's say the Settings can be created by using preference headers:

   ```
   <header
       android:fragment="com.xxx.settings.SettingsActivity$LoginFragment"
       android:title="Settings" android:icon="@drawable/ic_info_black_24dp" />
   ```
2. Load xml file for fragment

   ```
   public static class GeneralPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_settings);
           setHasOptionsMenu(true);
       }
   }
   ```
3. in the pref_settings.xml:

   ```
   <PreferenceScreen>
            ....
   ```

But the login form seems not a type of preferences...

[image]

Comment: Login preferences don't exist, create your own. Happy first day.. Never stop coding!

Comment: You're asking a question about Android development, but are showing an iPad screenshot. What exactly are you asking?

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in login preference.
You can subclass Preference override the methods and create your own layout.
See [Building a Custom Preference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#Custom)